# Setting context for development server [playframework 2.1.3]

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, netty

I am using Java / Play Framework 2.1.3.

In production, I build a war using the plugin, serve it in tomcat, and tell apache to redirect /myapp to my tomcat app.

In development, I start the server with:

play debug run

And the root for my dev instance is "/".

Now I would like to specify the context for my development instance. For example, I'd like the route to be /myapp but in the routes file I'd like root to still be "/", etc.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Play 2.1.x you can specify the context in your `application.conf` file.

```
application.context="/myapp"
```

...or you can do what I do and just run a local Apache instance and do the same thing as you do in prod :)

Comment: So, in the template when I want to refer to an asset I use:@routes.Assets.at("css/bootstrap.css")